# Add exception to the list of disabled signature algorithms on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm currently accessing some internal websites with Firefox. The certificates for the websites are signed with RSASSA-PSS, which is trusted by Chrome but not by Firefox. I understand that Mozilla prefer security over functionality ([RSASSA-PSS is not very secure after all](https://pkisolutions.com/pkcs1v2-1rsassa-pss/)), so I would like to enable RSASSA-PSS only on a Firefox only meant to browse internal websites (so that public sites with RSASSA-PSS sites will still fails). How do I do so? I didn't find any related key in about:config; maybe this can be done by tweaking some configuration files?

FYI I'm on Fedora. I don't want to add exception to sites one by one. Hopefully whitelist RSASSA-PSS would solve them all.